# Benefits of Separate Over Combined Apache Logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I was wondering if there are any benefits or common use-cases in which using separate Apache logs (access, agent, error, and referer) is better than using a single combined log file. I tried [Googling it](http://www.google.com/search?q=separate%20or%20combined%20apache%20logs), but it seems that an analysis has not really been done on this particular dilemma.

Traditionally I have used separate ones simply because it made sense to separate data into groups (of course in another way, it is actually *splitting* grouped data; i.e., any given access is being split into multiple pieces—which means viewing four files at the same time and trying to keep them synchronized to the same timestamp).

I haven’t used too many log analyzers, but I suspect that at least some work better (or at all) with combined logs.

So is there a good reason to use separate over combined?

Comment: If you're troubleshooting errors on a high-traffic site, it's going to be a lot easier to have a dedicated error log than trying to sift through a few million pageviews to find the errors.

Comment: Yes, a separate error log makes sense. But then it seems like a combined access/agent/referer log makes more sense than separating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a personal call that you have to make based on your environment and the way you work.  There are advantages and disadvantages to both.

The major advantage of a combined log (everything going to one file) is that it's written out contemporaneously: If an error occurs you see it right under the "access" line (the request) that caused it.
This can make troubleshooting a little easier if you don't have a huge volume of requests.

---

Conversely, separate log files makes sense whenever the volume of entries is so large as to be overwhelming when trying to troubleshoot a problem.

The "traditional" division for Apache is `access` and `error` logs --

- The Access log contains all the requests the server received (and the response codes it sent back), and sometimes additional useful bits like SSL Protocol, etc..
- The Error log contains, as its name implies, *errors* (CGI/PHP/etc. failures, exceptions, stack prints, debugging output).

When you're hunting down a problem you watch the error log and provoke the problem, and you get just the errors (as opposed to the error plus all the `GET` requests for CSS files, Javascript, images, etc. that your browser went to download before you reached the part where things crash).

---

You can take this further to an extreme (separate Access, Agent, Referrer, SSL, etc. logs), but personally I see no need to do that.  The traditional "Error" and "Access" (everything that isn't an error) logging is what you'll see in most deployments.

There may be a reason to keep *additional* dedicated logs for referrers, etc. if you're doing analysis or statistics, or you may omit that information from the Access log if you don't care about it, but I wouldn't subdivide logs to the point where you have to look in more than 2 places to troubleshoot a problem. That just winds up making more work for you.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought 404’s and such went into the error log, but they don’t, they go in `access.log`, so it makes total sense to keep an error log and a separate Access+Agent+Referer log because then the access-related items are grouped together by time. (Personally I don’t recall ever having to see one of those individually, and in fact have had to coordinate the three logs to get a sense of any given access.) I don’t know if any log-analyzers choke on separate logs, but it won’t matter if using a combined one (plus, log-analyzers don’t need the error log anyway, only the access log).

Answer (score 1):

I use different logs to separate key subjects which are running on the same server but are of totally different purpose (i.e. different sites or different type of security / sensitivity) as I find it easier to inspect, review and analyze as it cuts down the noise.

You could achieve similar results using grep too obviously.

Comment: Do you mean using per-virtual-host logs? I already do that and have no problem with it; I mean separate log files for access, agent, referer.

Comment: oh - well unless you really have to I wouldn't go there!